# Under what conditions on $a,b$ is $1/(a+bi)=(1/a)+(i/b)$?

Tags: complex-numbers

Question in proofs review in the complex numbers unit.

I expressed $1/(a+bi) = (a-bi)/(a^2+b^2)$

I then separated the two terms in the denominator to get $a/(a^2+b^2)-bi/(a^2+b^2)$

I then equated the term on the left to $(1/a)$ and the term on the right to $(i/b).$

I rearrange to solve for b in the first equation and am left with $b^2=0$, however b is found in the denominator, thus b can't equal zero.

Is there no solution to this question?

Comment: After equating real parts, we find that

$$\frac a {a^2 + b^2} = \frac 1 a \implies a^2 = a^2 + b^2 \implies b = 0$$

Comment: No there are no solutions.

Comment: The solution to the question is that there are no solutions to the equation. You showed that any such solution must have $b=0$, which can't happen.

Comment: Are you given that $a$ and $b$ are real?

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to solve the equation and get a condition:

$$\frac{1}{a+ib}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{i}{b}$$
$$1=1+\frac{ib}{a}+\frac{a}{b}-1=\frac{ib}{a}+\frac{a}{b}$$
$$ab=ib^2+a^2$$
$$0=ib^2+ab+a^2$$
$$b=\frac{-a \pm\sqrt{a^2-4i}}{2i}$$

As pointed out by others, if $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, then there is no solution.

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are complex, then this solution is ok.